# How do you delete files in the location: /usr/local/src?

Tags: delete

I tried to move a file into the rubbish bin (because I followed some instructions about installing sage and it involved moving a file to that directory) and it gave me errors saying that I didn't have permission. Even though I'm signed in as an administrator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T` and Use `sudo` like this.

```
cd /usr/local/src
sudo rm ./file-name
```

If you want to delete the entire content of a folder, you should use `-r` switch. like this:

```
cd /usr/local/src
sudo rm -r ./folder-name
```

Please, make sure you aren't deleting any system files. Also double check the file and folder name before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: I recommend never to use `rm -r` with a path containing a `/`. If you accidentally type a space in the middle, you might end up deleting the whole `/usr` tree or something. Rather, change to the parent directory first: `cd /usr/local/src`, check that it succeeded, `sudo rm -r folder-name`.

Comment: @BrentonHorne you can do this by clicking the gray tick icon at the left side of the answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm new to here. It's done!

Comment: Another option is to use the -i flag: `rm -ri /usr/local/src` , that will give confirmation prior to executing the deletion.