# How do I delete installed themes?

Tags: command-line, themes, uninstall, software-uninstall

I am new to Ubuntu and was excited by the freedom it gives.
So I installed a lot of themes and a lot of icons.

Now I want to get rid of them. And I don't know where are they installed. In Windows, I usually knew where a particular thing is installed. And it had been easy to uninstall things.

I am not aware of where things go after installation. Deleting the folder that I unzipped and then run `install.sh` from, do not remove it.
In which folder do I look at these things?

The same thing goes with software, once I install it. 
Removing the downloaded folder doesn't remove the software. My guess is that there is some place fixed where things go once I install them using the terminal as we don't specify their location in the terminal. What this location is?

Comment: You can check the `install.sh` scripts to see where the files were copied to.

Comment: What about those directly installed using terminal

Comment: *How* did you install directly using terminal? *Which exact* command(s) did you run?

Comment: Apt-get install xyz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I uninstall software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software) [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1008514/301745) covers install.sh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Installed using the installation script provided by the theme

It depends on the installation script (e.g. the `install.sh` file) to where the files would be copied. Open the script with a text-editor and examine its content to find out. Usual directories are:

- **Themes**

  - `/usr/share/themes/` (for a theme installed system-wide, i.e. with `sudo`)
  - `~/.themes/`
  - `~/.local/share/themes/`
- **Icons**

  - `/usr/share/icons/` (for an icon pack installed system-wide, i.e. with `sudo`)
  - `~/.icons/`
  - `~/.local/share/icons/`

#### Installed using `apt-get`

You can remove them by simply running

```
sudo apt-get remove <theme-package-name>
```

Comment: I moved to /usr/share/themes/ directory and tried deleting some themes that I installed and I could't

Comment: @rishabh That's a system folder, you don't have the permission to modify its contents. You need to use `sudo`. See these: https://askubuntu.com/q/194129/480481 && https://askubuntu.com/q/600392/480481

Comment: I installed too many themes, and I want to delete all and reset it to the default one. Should I delete all the folders in theme or one of these is the default one. I forgot which I installed and which were present there itself. One directory in theme is named default, should I remove all others except it?

Comment: one folder is named default, can i delete all the folders except it?

Comment: @rishabh **No**! The folder named "default" is most likely *not* the only pre-installed system theme. Ambiance, Radiance etc., if present, are most likely pre-installed themes. Only delete the ones you're absolutely certain about.

Comment: oh thanks, I didn't deleted Ambiance,Adwaita, Default,Emacs,HighContrast,Radiance,Raleigh. I think I didn't installed them. Thanks for your help.